# How to add adapter for OpenX , Criterio and Rubicon in Android Prebid sdk

Tags: prebid

How to setup OPenX and Criterio adapter in Prebid android sdk.

```
PrebidMobile.setPrebidServerHost(Host.RUBICON);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Web, current version of Prebid SDK (v1.2) does not support adapter customization.  Prebid SDK allows you to setup Prebid Sever that care about adapters